# Visual Studio 2022: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory" when compiling from the command line

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Today I installed Visual Studio Community 2022 on a Windows 10 computer. Visual Studio has never been installed on this computer before. During installation I selected the "Desktop development with C++" and "Game development with C++" workloads during install.

After installation is complete I can create a new console application in the IDE and it compiles successfully:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>test.cpp
1>ConsoleApplication.vcxproj -> C:\Users\redacted\source\repos\ConsoleApplication\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 11:41 AM and took 07.266 seconds ==========
```

However, using the command prompt to compile the same thing fails:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.7.2
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community>d:

D:\>type test.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

        printf("Hello\n");
}

D:\>cl test.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.37.32822 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory

D:\>
```

I noticed that in the developer command prompt, the INCLUDE environment variable is set to this...

`INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include`

...but stdio.h can only be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt`, which is also the file loaded in the IDE if I right-click the #include and choose Go To Document.

Adding this path to the INCLUDE environment variable does not fix the problem.

How can I fix this so I can compile from the developer command prompt?

Comment: Did you restart   the command prompt after adding path?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT No, I did `set INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt";%INCLUDE%` from within the command prompt and tried `cl.exe path.cpp` again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the vcvars*.bat files aren't creating all the needed environment variables. After checking on a different computer I found what the INCLUDE, LIB, and LIBPATH should look like:

```
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um

LIB=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.20348.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.20348.0\\um\x64

LIBPATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.20348.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.20348.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

After setting these I can now compile from the command prompt on this machine.

What great software you have, Microsoft...